# api to access android lint

Tags: android, lint

Does anyone know of a published API to access functionality inside Android Lint?

Here's what I want. In PMD it's possible to access the ruleset by first creating a ruleset factory, then iterating over PMD's built in rules:

> RuleSetFactory fact = new RuleSetFactory();
>
> ruleSetIterator= fact.getRegisteredRuleSets();

I want something like this for Android Lint, a way of accessing it's built in rules. When I run lint.bat --show I get a listing of Android Lint rules, I'd like to access this within a Java application.

I'm not finding much information so I may be on a snipe hunt here. Thought I'd ask SO for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question your purpose is not 100% clear to me. Why do you want to access the rules?

In general you have three options:

- Write your own custom Lint rules [1]
- Extend the Lint CLI by your own functionality [2][3]
- When executing Lint [2] define the checks to perform [4]

  1. http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/writing-a-lint-check
  2. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html
  3. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.lint/lint/24.1.3
  4. http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

Comment: What I was trying to do was run Lint for Android inside another Java application by accessing an API. This doesn't seem possible so I run lint from a command line from inside the app with the checks I want to perform. Your third choice above

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Unfortunately there is no such API in general. But in your case you could call the CLI (like you pointed out above) OR write a custom Lint application yourself, by extending the LintCliClient. I've done some similar here https://github.com/a11n/lint-junit-rule/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ad/android/tools/lint/TestLintClient.java In that case you have nearly full control. It comes closest to an "API to access lint". Hope that helps.